# Variable context paths or servlet paths in Spring Boot 3 application with embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

We have an application which used to run with embedded Jetty. Unfortunately, it is not possible to use Jetty well in Spring Boot 3, so we are trying to migrate to embedded Tomcat while also migrating to Spring Boot 3 from 2.7.x.

We have to be able to serve APIs with dynamic URL prefix (context path?), e.g., `/TENANT_ID/some/prefix/some/api` while having only `@RestController`/`@RequestMapping` for `/some/api`. With Jetty, we used to use a Jetty Customizer object, which would do `request.setAttribute(WebUtils.INCLUDE_CONTEXT_PATH_ATTRIBUTE, contextPath)` and change the `pathInfo` of the request. This no longer works with Spring Boot 3 and Tomcat.

My question is, **how would I handle dynamic prefix (servlet/context path?) systematically within Spring Framework?** Is it even possible?

I tried using `@RequestMapping` with regex parameter, e.g., `@RequestMapping(path = { "/{tenantId:[0-9]+}/some/prefix/**" })` on type level, but this syntax with the named parameter and regex does not seem to work on type level, it seems to work only on method level.

Comment: You can use an `UrlRewriteFilter` for that. Something like https://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ this can rewrite your URL to strip the tenant and use it as paramter/header etc. Else stick with Jetty and fix the issues you have with this.